# Why nothing happen when connecting UITableViewCell to UInavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I have UITableView with Static cells. I control-drag from one of these static cells to another UINavigationcontroller and select "Push". I notice nothing happen, when I run the app and tap on the static cells.

However, when I do the same thing & choose "Modal" it works fine. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use a "Push" transition when segueing between view controllers within a parent UINavigationController.

Your Navigation Controller should be your app's initial view controller.  Also when your table cell is tapped you'll want to segue to a View Controller (probably a custom UIViewController subclass), not a UINavigationController.

Make sure you have set your storyboard up with the following:

- A **UINavigationController** - this should be set as the Initial View Controller for your app.  Check that the checkbox "Is Initial View Controller" is checked in the Attributes inspector pane when the navigation controller is selected in the storyboard.
- A **UITableViewController** - this should be set at your navigation controller's Root View Controller (there should be an arrow pointing from the nav controller to the tableview controller that looks like a segue but has a different icon in the middle)
- Another **View Controller** - this is the view controller you want to segue to when clicking on your table cell, probably a customer UIVewController subclass you've created.  Note that it should probably NOT be a navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks !!!... I'm happy with "Modal" transition, it works fine with me. could I just continue using it?